# Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-desktop

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

When I am running sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full I will get the following error > E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Best
Mohsen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63694/unable-to-locate-package-ros-fuerte-desktop/) by [Mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/4999/mohsen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try  following this tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a ROS problem. This is an Ubuntu problem. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then, edit your question to include the output of the above code. The two statements above might actually fix the issue.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-05-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1